# Netsparker community edition: how to start with it?

Tags: security-testing, sql-injection

I like to do SQL injection security testing. So I installed [Netsparker](http://www.mavitunasecurity.com/netsparker/) (community edition 1.7). If any one have used this application to test SQL injection an web applications, then please tell me the basic steps to start up with it.

Answer (score 4):

I think much like any new application, once you get it up and running walk through any demos that may be provided.  If there are forums you might want to look at those as well.  Clearly as their site indicates as you are working with it be sure you are only doing it against a site that you are authorized to perform that sort of penetration testing on.

Answer (score 4):

If you are hoping to find the vulnerabilities through an automate scan
Open the application, click "Start New Scan", enter the address, and then start scan.

Please note, the community edition will really only find low hanging fruit.  Anything more difficult requires a subscription.

If you're hoping to do some manual testing for injection vulnerabilities, I don't know that this would be the best tool for you unless it is to see how it is detecting the vulnerabilities.

**Disclaimer**:  I've never actually seen or used Netsparker, community edition or otherwise until reading this question